# Concatenate and inserting in table

Tags: sql-server, insert, concatenation, rows

I have one table in my database, in my table I have 4 column 
NAME_1 NAME_2  LASTNAME_1 LASTNAME_2

Well now I'm adding one column more "FULL NAME" and I want concatenate NAME_1 NAME_ 2 LASTNAME_1 AND LASTNAME_2 and insert in FULL_NAME.

How do I do it?

```
NAME_1      NAME_2     LASTNAME_1    LASTNAME_2     
-------------------------------------------------
ALISON     NULL      LAWRENCE      NULL         
CARLOS     NULL      LOPEZ         RECINOS       
MEL        ANDREA    CHEW          PHELPS     



NAME1      NAME2     LASTNAME1    LASTNAME2     FULL_NAME     
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ALISON     NULL      LAWRENCE      NULL        ALISON LAWRENCE    
CARLOS     NULL      LOPEZ         RECINOS    CARLOS LOPEZ RECINOS   
MEL        ANDREA    CHEW          PHELPS     MEL ANDREA CHEW PHELPS
```

Comment: You should make this a computed column instead of a persistent column. See the code from RADAR but use that as the value for your computed column. If you keep the data in it's own columns you will always have your values out of date.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ISNULL and concatenation operator + and set the value

```
UPDATE Table1
SET  FULL_NAME = ISNULL(NAME_1,'') + 
                 ISNULL(NAME_2,'') + 
                 ISNULL(LASTNAME_1,'') + 
                 ISNULL(LASTNAME_2,'')
```

Comment: This is definitely the right way from the code side but I would recommend to the OP to make this a computed column instead. That way you don't duplicate the data and it is always current.

Comment: @Sean Lange, you are right, that is the correct approach